# Tkinter Button commands in loops execut always last command

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am not experienced programmer and I could not find a solution for this problem.
I would like to create a long list of subroutines with their button description and use the code below to create the buttons. But such code assigns always last subroutine from the list to all buttons.

```
self.row=Frame(root)
self.programs=(('description1',p1),('description2',p2))
for self.program in self.programs:
    self.b= Button(self.row, text=self.program[0], command=lambda event="":self.program[1]())
    self.row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
```

It runs fine except all buttons are executing p2. How to solve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of late binding, the `self.program` is determine when the callback is called, not when it is created.

Use default parameter to avoid the problem:

```
self.row=Frame(root)
self.programs=(('description1',p1),('description2',p2))
for naem, callback in self.programs:
    self.b = Button(self.row, text=self.program[0],
                    command=lambda callback=callback: callback())  # <---
    self.row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
```

BTW, the callback set using `command` does not called with an argument.